# If $y=ax^be^{-cx}$ then $x=g(y)$, find $g$

Tags: inverse, lambert-w

I have this function

$$y=0.384394\cdot x^{0.341429}\cdot e^{-0.004749 x}$$

Based on this function I would like to know how I can I get
$x=g(y)$.

Comment: what makes you expect the existance of a close form for the reciprocal ?

Comment: Well I am not quite sure. I was hoping to solve x=f(y) based on the parameters.

Comment: But do you really need a close form ? A numerical solving, or an approximate solution via Taylor series won't be sufficient for your needs ?

Answer (score 2):

Write it as 
$$ y = a x^b e^{-cx}$$
where we assume $a, b, c > 0$.
Then
$$ (y/a)^{1/b} =  x e^{-cx/b}$$
so with $t = -cx/b$ we have 
$$ -\dfrac{c\; (y/a)^{1/b}}{b} = t e^{t} $$
Then $$t = W\left(- \frac{c\; (y/a)^{1/b}}{b}\right)$$
i.e.
$$x = - \dfrac{b}{c}\; W\left(- \frac{c\; (y/a)^{1/b}}{b}\right)$$
where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert W function.  If $0 < c (y/a)^{1/b}/b < 1/e$, there are two real branches (the $-1$ and $0$ branches), while if $ c (y/a)^{1/b}/b > 1/e$ neither branch is real.  Here's a plot, with the $-1$ branch in blue and the $0$ branch in red.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for
the Lambert W function.

Look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

This solves
$y = ze^z$
for $z$ as a function of $y$.

The next step is to
convert your function
to this form.